# How to use a flutter module in a flutter app?

Tags: flutter, module, flutter-add-to-app

I have a flutter module and I want to add it to another existing flutter app.

The module is a close-source sdk from a client so it cannot be converted into a package.

I know there is the add-to-app functionality but it only works on native apps.

Is there any way to add-to-app a module to a Flutter app?